# Rename function to move a file between folders does not work properly

Tags: php

```
header ("Content-type: octet/stream");
header ("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$file.";");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
readfile($file);`
```

Here is my code to download an audio file.
It was successful and the file is saved to system downloads folder.
Now I want to have an application specific download folder and save all downloaded music files to that folder only so that I can use directory listing to show all those downloads.

I tried coding like:

```
rename('C:\Users\user2\Downloads/'.$file,
       'C:\Users\user2\Music\Playlists/'.$file);
```

But it's not working all the time.
Any Help is Appreciated.

Comment: Your mixing `\ ` and `/` in your rename function, that cannot be good? hmm, reading about it, and it seems to be allowed. Sorry, I never used PHP on Windows.

Comment: What is the content of `$file`?

Comment: rename($souce.'/'.$file, $destination.'/'.$file); doesn't made a benefit.using the previous code I was able to move the files at some instances, but not all time the desired output is getting.

Comment: audio file with extension .mp3

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Usually I The file is moved to destination at the second try

Comment: What does your first code snippet have to do with your second code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

modify your code as shown, since you are working on windows machine, pls change the slash

```
rename("C:\Users\user2\Downloads\$file", "C:\Users\user2\Music\Playlists\$file");
```

Comment: No, It Ends up with a syntax Error

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING                       Is it problem with placing of my second code snippet?I placed it in the same page as that of the first code snippet